# using node.js with a remote GraphicsMagick server

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

I have node.js installed on one server.  I have graphicsmagick https://github.com/aheckmann/gm installed on another server.  The graphics files themselves are also stored on the graphicsmagick server.  I want to install & setup the node gm module so that the work/processing is done on the graphicsmagick server.  However, after reading through the documentation, I don't see how to do this.  Of course, I can install graphicsmagic on the same server as node, and have it work properly.  But I don't want to have the heavy image processing happening on the same server as node.  Is this possible to separate the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `gm` module is not a server, you need to write a service to manipulate the images with `gm`.

Something like this using express.js:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express.createServer();

app.get('/:image', function (req, res, next) {
  // set headers here

  gm('/path/to/my/' + req.params.image)
    .resize('200', '200')
    .stream(function (err, stdout, stderr) {
      if (err) next(err);
      stdout.pipe(res);
    });
});

app.listen(8000);
```